# Nested multiplatform libraries usage with cocoapods intergration

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

In Android world, I could add a dependency in a module, for any module which add this module as a dependency, it could use API from that dependency as will. e.g. facebook sdk -> utils module -> foo module -> main app module, both foo module & main app module could use facebook sdk API as well.

How do I did the same thing in multiplatform world (or in iOS world)?
facebook iOS sdk pod -> utils module -> foo module -> iOS main project

I've tried to add pod only in utils module, but neither foo & main could access facebook iOS API. If I add same pod in foo module, it can't access Facebook API neither.

Or should I use another dependency management tool other than cocoapods?

Comment: i have tested your scenario with my KMMT (https://github.com/jittya/KMMT). Look like it works similar to android. i have a analytics module which is added as dependency in injector module and i am able to use the Mixpanel class from ios source set.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you would like to have something like [Export dependencies to binaries](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-build-native-binaries.html#export-dependencies-to-binaries) in the end. However, I'm not sure this will work for dependencies between Kotlin modules. For dependencies between them, I would recommend using the `api` dependencies [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#dependency-types) and adding pods for each module individually.
I mean, core module's build.gradle.kts should contain only

```
...
kotlin {
    ios()

    cocoapods {
        ios.deploymentTarget = "13.5"

        summary = "CocoaPods test library"
        homepage = "https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin"

        pod("FBSDKCoreKit")
    }
}
...
```

login module is having both cocoapods and core dependencies:

```
...
kotlin {
    ios()

    framework {
            // Mandatory properties
            // Configure fields required by CocoaPods.
            summary = "Some description for a Kotlin/Native module"
            homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"
            // Framework name configuration. Use this property instead of deprecated 'frameworkName'
            baseName = "MyFramework"

            // Optional properties
            // (Optional) Dynamic framework support
            isStatic = false
            // (Optional) Dependency export
            export(project(":core"))
            transitiveExport = true
            // (Optional) Bitcode embedding
            embedBitcode(BITCODE)
        }
        pod("FBSDKCoreKit")
        pod("FBSDKLoginKit")
    }
...
    sourceSets {
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api(project(":core"))
            }
        }
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only export a single Kotlin Xcode Framework. It's kind of a "big binary" that has all of it's dependencies. If "utils module" and "foo module" are both Kotlin modules, you should collect them into a single Kotlin Xcode Framework.

Comment: Thanks. The scenario I need is that a core kotlin module which use Facebook Core API, and a login kotlin module which use Facebook Core & Login API & my core module. All of them would finally export as a single library into Xcode.